# Is there a more efficient way of using triggers in WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Currently I'm trying (in C#) to colour a DataGrid's cells based on their value. My DataGrid's columns are set to Days of the Week (Monday-Friday) and I can currently do this, but it is extremely lengthy. This is how it currently is:

```
<DataGrid Name="mapDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="27,29,27,10" ColumnWidth="73">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle> 
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>

                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                                <!-- Check if cell has value of 0 in the 'Monday' column. -->

                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Monday}" Value="0"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />


                         </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>

                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!-- Check if cell has value of 1 in the 'Monday' column. -->

                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Monday}" Value="1"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                ...
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

As you could imagine, doing this from a value of 0 to a value of 3 (my maximum) for every day of the week results in some extremely lengthy XAML code. Is there a way to reduce the length and make my code more efficient or dynamic?

**UPDATE:** Is this what you mean, @Freeman ?

```
<dg:DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style
       TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumn}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type dg:DataGridColumn}}">
       <Setter
          Property="Background"
          Value="{Binding ItemColour}" />
    </Style>
 </dg:DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Although in my case, I'd use a converter to convert the value to the colour?

Comment: I would recommand you to have those logics on your VM and just bind the `Background` color of `itemstemplate` in view

Answer (score 0):

You can write a converter class

```
public class DayToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // logic here
        if(value == "Monday") return Brushes.Blue; //etc...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // logic here
    }
}

<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CurrentDay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource DayToBackgroundConverter }}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this colour a whole row though, instead of a single cell?

Comment: Yes, it can be by using ItemContainerStyle of datagrid